# Python 3 files are assigned to wrong filename which I specify

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, newline

This is a script that downloads an image from the web by first specifying its url. It then downloads it and stores it in my Downloads directory. The name the image is assigned is a random line from Random_filenames.txt, which just has the words Image1 to Image 10 all on new lines. Once I run and check the my Downloads directory, the name is Image3?.jpg or Image8?.jpg. Where is the ? coming from??? Please help me get rid of it. I'm using a mac with pycharm and the url in the code below is fake it's just a sample.

```
import random
import urllib.request   

direc = '/Users/phil/Downloads/'

def dwnld_web_img(url):
    r = open('Random_filenames.txt', 'r')
    name = random.choice(r.readlines())
    full_name = name + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, direc + full_name)

dwnld_web_img("https://www.website.com/123456.jpg")
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you sure that the Random_filenames file contains what you say it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines read from the file using `readlines()` have a newline character at the end of each item. You should strip this when building the filename:

```
full_name = name.strip() + ".jpg"
```